# What is this error: "no appropriate default constructor available"?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am getting:

> main.cpp(13): error C2512: 'myPlayer' : no appropriate default
>   constructor available

Here is the code that it is referring to:

```
    myPlayer player;
```

Here is the constructor:

```
myPlayer (int myHealth, int myDamage, int myMoney, int myWeaponID, int myClass) : health(myHealth), damage(myDamage), money(myMoney),
    weapon_id(myWeaponID), p_class(myClass) {}
```

Also, how can I show the number for each line on Visual Studio 11?

Comment: Do you have a default constructor (one with no arguments) for that class? If you don't, you need to declare one.

Answer (score 6):

Your constructor is declared to take 5 parameters, all of type `int`. You're not supplying any parameters.

Your choices are to write a constructor that doesn't require arguments, or else supply the arguments when you construct the object, like: `myPlayer player(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

Comment: Option 3: give all of the parameters default values. Option 4 (C++11): Use in-class member initializers for all members. Now that I've provided something, since my teacher was so specific, your first paragraph should end with arguments, since they're what you give the function.

Comment: @chris: Your option 3 is really option 1 -- providing default values is simply one way to eliminate the requirement for arguments when you create an object. Option 4 is pretty much the same too --  another mechanism to eliminate the requirement to pass arguments when you construct an object.

Comment: Same idea, yes, but different methods. Depending on the situation, one might fit in better than the others.